# What is the term for whatever is being differentiated?

Tags: derivatives, terminology

When we integrate a function:

$ \int^b_a {2\over x^2} dx$

The expression to be integrated (is this case $ {2\over x^2} $) is referred to as the **integrand**.

When we differentiate a function:

$ {d \over dx } {2 \over x^2}$

Is there a word to describe the expression to to be differentiated? For instance, if I wanted to say "In the above equation, two over x squared is the --------", what would I fill in the blank?

Comment: Given function??

Comment: Clearly, it's the differentiand. Though, strangely, Google doesn't recognize this term.

Comment: Follow-up question: is there any reason why you would need such a term?  I don't think "integrand" is used beyond calculus either.

Comment: @Lost I'm writing a program where I have a higher-order function that accepts another function as input and differentiates it, and I'm looking for something to name the argument.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Fair enough. As others have said, there doesn't seem to be a commonly used term, so anything is fair game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call it the **differentiand** and everyone will know what you mean.  It's unambiguous, but certainly not in regular use.

Comment: "Differentiand" is horrible! If you need to invent a word, "differand" is surely better.

Comment: I'm just following the horrible rules of Latin.

Comment: Yes OK, but why?

Comment: There is no really good answer to "why".  First: symmetry is something mathematicians love. Why name the intgrand one way but the differentiand another? Second: Latin was the language of Leibniz' and Newton's papers which formalized infinitessimal calculus. If we were inventing a new concept I might use a new language, but since we're finding a name for something well known in the 17th century, using the language of its inventors seems apropos.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just call it "the expression being differentiated."

Answer (score 0):

We say "operand" for thing being operated on.  So if we differentiate, we should say, "differetiand." although the shortening by Tony K might be an improvement on this messy word.